Making certain lights in scene not react to volumetrics (eevee)?
I have a scene with multiple lights and volumetric fog.
If i want one of my lights not to react to the volumetrics while still lighting my meshes, how can I go about achieving that in Eevee?
Thanks!

Lights don’t react to volumetrics, volumetrics react to lights. As for how to keep a volumetric from being influenced by a light, I’m fairly certain that’s impossible with EEVEE at the moment.

@TheLabCat Impossible? Just reduce the effect on the Volume in the light settings... see my answer.

@GordonBrinkmann OK, I did not know that setting existed. Thank you I guess.

In the settings of the light, set the value for Volume to 0. Here the white light is visible in the volumetrics, the blue light is not but still shining on the objects:

In Cycles you can disable Volume Scatter under Ray Visibility, but that is just on/off. In EEVEE you have the advantage of having lights with varying strong effect on the volumetrics by choosing values between 0 and 1.
